# Check condition after each line of code in Python

Tags: python, popupwindow, multiple-conditions

I have a function with a script which read out some data and do some actions in the SAP-GUI. Perhaps, there pop up a message-window in the GUI which I want to catch to proceed with the script. To do so I have to check the condition, if a popup occurs, after each line of my script.

**What I have:**

```
def mysap_script():
    command1
    command2
    command3
```

**What I have to do, but want to avoid:**

```
def mysap_script():
    command1
    if message_window opens: do some actions
    command2
    if message_window opens: do the same action as before
    command3
    if message_window opens: do the same action as before
```

Is there an efficient and easier way for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the commands with a function that check the condition you need to check.

```
def wrapped_cmd(cmd):
    if cond:
        something()
    cmd()
```

and call this instead, like this

```
def mysap_script():
    wrapped_cmd(cmd)
```

Comment: That means I have to pass each command as argument to function `def wrapped(cmd)` and the result will be:
`def mysap_script():wrapped_cmd(command1)       wrapped_cmd (command2)...`   ?

Comment: Yes, also you can get a bit fancy by wrapping each command with decorators. So you can decorate them and call directly.

Comment: Understood, but the idea is to shorten the writing, even with decorators I have to wrap each commandlines  in functions and  call it separately.